# MySQL Database display all data issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to display all the data inside a specific table in my database. I am getting this error in trying to do so.

```
    Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in      /home/content/59/11513559/html/bg/showscore.php on line 23
```

**This is my php file:**

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    //connect to db
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder");


     $table=$_SESSION['gamecode'];

     mysqli_select_db( $con,'dbname') or die("Database selection failed: " .      mysql_error());
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $table");


     function tableme($result){
     $header='';
     $rows='';
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 if (!$result) { // add this check.
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); 
     if($header==''){
        $header.='<th>'; 
        $rows.='<tr>'; 
        foreach($row as $key => $value){ 
            $header.='<td>'.$key.'</td>'; 
            $rows.='<td>'.$value.'</td>'; 
        } 
        $header.='</th>'; 
        $rows.='</tr>'; 
     }else{
        $rows.='<tr>'; 
        foreach($row as $value){ 
            echo "<td>".$value."</td>"; 
        } 
        $rows.='</tr>'; 
      }
     } 
      return '<table>'.$header.$rows.'</table>';
     }
      echo tableme($result);
```

**This is line 23:**    `mysqli_select_db(" . $table . ",$con) or die(mysql_error());`

Im not sure what else i would need to add to this line. Or what is wrong with it that would cause this error. Also i know my session is working just fine i have called it and displayed it on may other pages to add/remove data from the table.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where you define `$table?`

Comment: Change the order of the parameters: put $con first. Also, don't mix `mysql` and `mysqli` calls - it won't work. Finally, don't use `mysql` at all: it's deprecated. Use `mysqli` or PDO

Comment: I defined '$table' in the '$_SESSION' line... thanks for that i did change it I also made sure i changed the 'mysql' to 'mysqli' i noticed i assigned the '$table' variable wrong and changed it to '$table=$_SESSION['gamecode'];' i am now getting a error that says database selection failed...

Comment: Do a `var_dump($table);` on the line after you assign to `$table` to make sure it's getting the name of the database you need it to.

Comment: @st15jap - you're not setting `$table` in the `$_SESSION` line. You're setting `$_SESSION` in that line, to the value of what's in `$table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **php documentation** says :

```
bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )
```

So this line :

```
 mysqli_select_db(" . $table . ",$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Should be :

```
 mysqli_select_db($con," . $table . ") or die(mysql_error());
```

AND :`" . $table . "` SHOULD be the name of your database(Not name of a table) and **without** `spaces` and `.`

Comment: Wow you are absolutely right. It now connects to the correct database. so to connect to the table should i be using `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM . $table . ");`

Comment: Like this : $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $table");

Comment: ok, i made those changes. I updated my code above to reflect what should be correct. I do not get any error messages, however i am not getting the table displayed like it should.

Comment: By chance do you see anything else that would cause this to not work? I thank you for everything you have done with answering my initial question

Answer (score 0):

As the warning is saying, first parameter should be mysqli resource

```
 mysqli_select_db(  $con,$table) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Answer deleted sir! ;)